# null jSON object, error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length'

Tags: javascript, json, getjson

I have a script where I get some data through JSON, this is like :

```
$.getJSON('phpfile', function(data) { ...
```

it works perfectly when I receive some data but when its empty, I get the next error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Where I get this error is a line like this one :

```
if(data==null){
 //actions if the JSON is doesnt give me data
}else{
 //actions if I get data
}
```

What I want is to control when JSON sends data or not, how can I do it ?

EDIT: I get the error with $.each(data, function(key, val) { when data is a null object, when json doesn't get any data.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `What I want is to control when JSON sends data or not, how can I do it ?` The server sends you JSON data or no response, based on the logic in your server side code.

Comment: When I dont have data with JSON it returns null instead of data

Comment: If there's no data, why shouldn't it return `null`?

Comment: do you think handling when error appears is a solution for your problem? `try ($.getJSON('phpfile', function(data) { ...
) catch(e) { ... when error .... }`

Comment: And what exactly are those "actions" taken when "data" is `null`?

Comment: what I want is to append a html when no data is received by JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.getJSON('phpfile', function handleSuccess(data) {
    if(!data){ 
          //handle if null or undefined
    }else{
         //actions if I get data
    }
    }).error(function handleErrorCase(){
        //handle error i.e. your server returning something other 200 or not json
    };
```